# Docusign Python SDK Authentication Example Error: Bad Request

Tags: python, json, jwt, docusignapi

I am trying to use the Docusign Rest API  and attempted to follow the sample code on the Python SDK on Github here: https://github.com/docusign/docusign-python-client. I've replaced the necessary values with those obtained from Docusign (keys, urls etc) but the example seems to break down at the following line:

```
api_client.configure_jwt_authorization_flow(private_key_filename, oauth_base_url, integrator_key, user_id, 3600)
```

Before then, the code takes the given information and creates the url to authenticate as I understand it. I've manually accessed this link and it seems to work; it asks me for permission to allow the program to act on my behalf and then redirects me to the redirect uri with a code added to the uri. My problem is that when it executes the next line (the one I posted above), it results in this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-40-84847e506c37>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/santi/Desktop/docusign/untitled0.py', wdir='C:/Users/santi/Desktop/docusign')

  File "C:\Users\santi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\santi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/santi/Desktop/docusign/untitled0.py", line 501, in <module>
    api_client.configure_jwt_authorization_flow(private_key_filename, oauth_base_url, integrator_key, user_id, 3600)

  File "C:\Users\santi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docusign_esign\api_client.py", line 126, in configure_jwt_authorization_flow
    post_params=self.sanitize_for_serialization({"assertion": assertion, "grant_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer"}))

  File "C:\Users\santi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docusign_esign\api_client.py", line 430, in request
    body=body)

  File "C:\Users\santi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docusign_esign\rest.py", line 244, in POST
    body=body)

  File "C:\Users\santi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docusign_esign\rest.py", line 200, in request
    raise ApiException(http_resp=r)

ApiException: (400)
Reason: Bad Request
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Cache-Control': 'private', 'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'X-AspNetMvc-Version': '5.2', 'X-DocuSign-TraceToken': '15fb83c2-9054-4522-b5ed-b77646fe1c4b', 'X-DocuSign-Node': 'DA2DFE4', 'Date': 'Sun, 05 Aug 2018 19:35:12 GMT', 'Content-Length': '11'})
HTTP response body: b'Bad Request'
```

I've googled the problem and found some similar errors on here but none that helped me out much. Following the traceback takes me into the api_client.py and rest.py files but I wasn't able to decipher much. In the end the origin in the error seems to be in line 200 of rest.py where an exception is raised because a value unknown to me is not within the proper range. I'm not sure what is causing the bad request on my end. Has anyone had a similar experience or might know what the issue is? I'd appreciate it a lot, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting exactly the same error at the same line.

The account specific inputs to api_client.configure_jwt_authorization_flow() are:

1. the private_key_filename (which is processed correctly to get a JWT token)
2. the oauth_base_url (which is hard coded in the example as 
   "account-d.docusign.com")
3. the integrator_key (copy-pasted from my account)
4. the user_id

It turns out that the user_id value should the API Username code. That fixed the problem. I found the answer here:
[DocuSign Python SDK - API Exception 400 - 'Bad Request'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51623118/docusign-python-sdk-api-exception-400-bad-request)

Hope it solves your problem too!

Comment: Thanks a lot this fixed it perfectly!